# Trouble with adding Dynamic inputs on form Post

Tags: javascript, php, html, input, dynamic

i'm still a student so i'm learning php and html5, and i'm doing a practice excercise where i have to submit the name and last name of a teacher, their salary, and how many students they have on each course, if a course have more than 20 students the teacher will get a 10% salary raise but only one time, so it doesn't matter if the teacher have more than 1 course with 20 students he will only get 10% raise once.

The thing is that the teacher can have 1, 2 or even 5 courses but it changes every time, so i'm learning to do dynamic inputs, so far the code works with 1 course, but when i add another input and do the submit, only recognizes the first input, not the dynamic one, i've watched a lot of vids, read a lot of guides but nothing seems to be working so i think that i did something wrong but don't know what

This is my code
Html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Formulario Profesores</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta charset="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/customcss.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="bg-grdnt">
    <header>
        <h1 class="text-center">Formulario Profesores</h1>
    </header>

<div class="card bg-primary form-cntr" id="formulario">
    <div class="card-header bg-primary text-light text-center">
        Formulario
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form class="p-3 bg-light" id="form1" action="action.php" method="POST">
            <h4 class="card-title text-center">Calculo de Salario de Profesores</h4>
            <div class="form-group text-justify">
                <label>Nombre</label><br>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nom" id="nom">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-justify">
                <label>Apellido</label><br>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="ape" id="ape">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-justify">
                <label>Sueldo</label><br>
                <input class="form-control" type="number" name="sue" id="sue">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-justify" id="contenedor_secciones">
                <p>Estudiantes por Secciones: (max. 5 Secciones)</p>
                <div class="form-inline" id="sec">
                <label>Seccion 1</label>
                <input class="form-control mx-sm-3" type="number" name="sez_1" id="sez_1" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add" value="Agregar Secciones">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="formsub" value="Calcular">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

    <footer>

    </footer>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/javascript/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/javascript/customjs.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

customjs

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField = 5;
    var addButton = $('#add');
    var wrapper = $('#contenedor_secciones'); 
    var x = 1; 
    //var fieldHTML = '<div class="form-inline" id="sec'+x+'"><label>Seccion '+x+'</label><input class="form-control mx-sm-3" type="number" name="seccion" id="sez" value=""><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary mx-sm-3" id="delete" value="-">'; //New input field html 

    $(addButton).click(function(){
        if(x < maxField){ 
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-inline" id="sec'+x+'"><label>Seccion '+x+'</label><input class="form-control mx-sm-3" type="number" name="sez_'+x+'" id="sez_'+x+'" value=""><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary mx-sm-3" id="delete" value="-">'); 
        }
        else{
            alert("Numero maximo de secciones alcanzado");
        }
    });
    

    $(wrapper).on('click', '#delete', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#sec'+x).last().remove();
        x--; 
    });
});
```

Action.php

```
<?php

  $nombre = test_input($_POST["nom"]);
  $apellido = test_input($_POST["ape"]);
  $sueldo = test_input($_POST["sue"]);
  $cont= count($_POST);
  $tr= ($_POST["sez_2"]);

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
};

if ($cont=4) {
  $s1="sez_1";
  if ($_POST[$s1]!='') {
    $ss1= test_input($_POST[$s1]);
    if ($ss1>20) {
      $bon = ($sueldo * 0.1);
      $nsue = ($sueldo+$bon);
      echo "$nombre $apellido <br>";
      echo "Usted tiene un sueldo de: $sueldo<br>";
      echo "Pero como maneja una o mas secciones de 20 alumnos<br>Obtendra una bonificiacion de: $bon<br>";
      echo "Haciendo que su nuevo sueldo sea de $nsue";
      echo "$tr";
    }
    else{
      echo "$nombre $apellido <br>";
      echo "Usted tiene un sueldo de: $sueldo";
    };
  };
};



?>
```

I was trying to echo the post of the second input to see if i was getting the data but it doesn't work, so if anybody can help me, pointing me on the right direction or writting the correct code i really appreciate it.

btw i'm a spanish speaker student, so that's why some text or code might be on spanish.

Edit: This is the Customcss.css that i'm using, i forgot to add it (i don't know if it's important so here it is).

```
.bg-grdnt{
    background-image:linear-gradient(#8080ff, #e6e6ff);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.form-cntr{
    width: 25rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border:2px solid #0388fc;
}
```

Comment: Suggest you consider naming the fields using `name="ape[]"` Then each field is delivered as an array

Comment: Ok, i don't know what happened, i've tried to add the "[]" on each name, and modified the code, but it gave me like 4 different errors, so i've panic and change it back, and now it do sends the dynamic input, but that means that something else is wrong in my code right? becouse the count should work with 4 and not 5 $_POST?